# Mongodb sharded cluster $in VS $or

Tags: mongodb, sharding

If I have MongoDB shurded cluster in sharded key: "my_key".
I have to find in collection pack documents (about 10-500 items) with different my_key's.
Foe example:

db.test.find({my_key: {$in:[1,3,5,67,45,56...]}})

Mongos knows where chunks with 'my_key' stored.
Can mongos split my query to small queries to exact shards where documents stored? Or mongos will send this query to ALL shards?

And the same question about $or

db.test.find({$or:[{my_key: 1},{my_key: 3},{my_key: 5}...]})

Comment: The two queries are the same thing. So what is your question? Does this "scatter gather" across shards?

Comment: No, my question about how many shards will involved to query execution.

Comment: Thats funny because your question is titled *$in VS $or*. To which the main answer is *"no difference"*.

Comment: I see. But in title present sharded cluster. May by in cluster $in and $or have difference :)

Answer (score 3):

I have run tests.

If $in contains values only from one shard mongos will send SINGLE_SHARD query.

If $in contains values from several shards then mongos will send SHARD_MERGE query only for shards than contains needed data (not all cluster).

Comment: Which is what I told you already. "Scatter Gather" means go out to each shard where the data is contained ( "Scatter" ) and then bring all that data back together ( "Gather" ). And of course if all chunks are on one shard there is no point in sending a query request to a shard that does not contain the data.